# Connecting to DashDB on Bluemix using Bluemix PHP App

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I'm failing to connect to the dashdb on bluemix using php. I tried troubleshooting and I think that my error is within the function $conn = db2_connect( $conn_string, "", "" );

What values do I need to put in the empty inverted commas? Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Starter Application</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $usern = $_POST['un'];
    $passw = $_POST['pw'];
    if( getenv( "VCAP_SERVICES" ) )
    {
        # Get database details from the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable
        #
        # *This can only work if you have used the Bluemix dashboard to
        # create a connection from your dashDB service to your PHP App.
        #
        $details  = json_decode( getenv( "VCAP_SERVICES" ), true );
        $dsn      = $details [ "dashDB" ][0][ "credentials" ][ "dsn" ];
        //$ssl_dsn  = $details [ "dashDB" ][0][ "credentials" ][ "ssldsn" ];

        # Build the connection string
        #
        $driver = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};";
        $conn_string = $driver . $dsn;     # Non-SSL
        //$conn_string = $driver . $ssl_dsn; # SSL
            echo $conn_string;
        $conn = db2_connect( $conn_string, "", "" );
        //echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
        if( $conn )
        {
            echo "<p>Connection succeeded.</p>";
            db2_close( $conn );
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>Connection failed.</p>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
        //echo "<p> <a href='index.php'>Missing DB Connection.</p>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: The two parameters you are asking about have to be empty strings according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php. In addition to the error message can you share what your conn_string look like? Mask the values for UID and PWD before posting.

Comment: DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-entry-*********-****.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=**********;PWD=*************;

Comment: From the logs, I get this error: "Call to undefined function odbc_connect()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution from bluemix support. The dashdb driver was not properly installed. I got the driver here: https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php

It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing double quotes with single quotes

> $conn = db2_connect($conn_string, ' ', ' ' );

Comment: Hi RiyaMRoy I just tried that and it's not working also, I get the following error on the logs: "Call to undefined function odbc_connect()"

Comment: I think the code is not displayed well in this comment box, please refer to my initial question, it has the entire page code pasted. Thank you

Comment: Please refer to this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_php.html